# DataTable check if row is last in collection

Tags: c#, datatable

Say I have a DataTable like so:

state of D is DataViewRowState.Deleted and lets say O are rows that have not been touched

```
index: 0 | state: O  
index: 1 | state: O  
index: 2 | state: O  
index: 3 | state: D
index: 4 | state: D
```

Say I delete the row at index 2 (I set the row state to deleted). Is there a way to know if row at index 1 is the last non-deleted row in the collection without "walking forward" and checking the rows state of each record after index 1?

Comment: "walking forward" means "walking backwards", since you want to find the first non-deleted _before_ the deleted?

Comment: Subclass datagridview and store this info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
int deletedIndex = 2;
DataRow firstNonDeletedBeforeDeletedIndex = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where((row, index) => index < deletedIndex && row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    .LastOrDefault(); // null if none found
```